# Infeasible output with scipy.signal.sosfilt

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signal-processing

I am designing a 3rd order Butterworth filter in Python which I am testing on a composition of sinusoids -

```
t=np.linspace(0,100,1000)
sig=np.sin(2*np.pi*10*t)+np.sin(2*pi*20*t)+np.sin(2*pi*30*t)
sos=signal.butter(3,15,'hp',analog=True,output='sos')
filtered=signal.sosfilt(sos,sig)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,sig)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,filtered)
plt.show()
```

After executing the above, I see a output waveform like this -
[Original signal and filtered signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np04k.png)

Please point out the mistake in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating an analog filter as a digital filter, but that doesn't work. In the call of `butter`, change the argument to `analog=False` to create a digital (i.e. discrete time) signal.